# Typescript - stringify class without dynamically added properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I have set of typescript objects that has been initiated, but in the code I need to dynamically add some properties to those object. If I need to serialize the object by stingifying it - how can I do it so it won't include dynamically added properties? As I have loads of classes and inner classes I am looking for a generic approach rather one by one case.

So as an example I have a class defined in the following way:

```
 export class Car {

  public colour: string = '';
  public model: string = '';
  public diesel?: boolean = false;

  constructor () {}
}
```

Now in the code I am setting the above car as a one that I drive at the moment:

```
let car: Car = new Car();
car.model = 'modelA';
car.colour = 'black';

car['active'] = true;
```

And then somewhere in the code I have to take the active car and serialize the object so I can i.e. send the data to the server:

```
JSON.stringify({'data': car});
```

What I am looking for is now the string representation of the object without the dynamically added properties, but approach to be generic so I don't have to describe what I want to remove.

All help wanted ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maintain a list of the "known keys" and use them when serializing:

```
class Car {
    private static keys = ["colour", "model", "diesel"];

    public colour: string = '';
    public model: string = '';
    public diesel?: boolean = false;

    constructor() { }

    toJsonString(): string {
        const data = {};
        Car.keys.forEach(key => data[key] = this[key]);

        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
}
```

You can use decorators to create this static list.

Or:

```
class Car {
    public colour: string = '';
    public model: string = '';
    public diesel?: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        this.toJsonString = function (keys) {
            const data = {};
            keys.forEach(key => data[key] = this[key]);

            return JSON.stringify(data);
        }.bind(this, Object.keys(this));
    }

    toJsonString: () => string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a car, and it will only have the normal properties. Then loop over each of its properties, and copy the value from the other car:

```
let car: Car = new Car();
car.model = 'modelA';
car.colour = 'black';

car['active'] = true;

let withoutDynamics = new Car();

for (let prop in withoutDynamics) {
    // Check for hasOwnProperty if you like, depending on whether you
    // properties from the prototype
    withoutDynamics[prop] = car[prop];
}

JSON.stringify({'data': withoutDynamics });
```

You could factor this out into a generic function to be used with other classes (if they have a constructor that takes no parameters):

```
function noDynamics<T>(type: { new (): T; }, withDynamics: T): T {
    let withoutDynamics = new type();

    for (let prop in withoutDynamics) {
        withoutDynamics[prop] = withDynamics[prop];
    }

    return withoutDynamics;
}

JSON.stringify({'data': noDynamics(Car, car) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an array of the original keys in a property and use a custom [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) implementation in your class to control that only the original keys get serialized:

```
export class Car {

    public colour: string = '';
    public model: string = '';
    public diesel?: boolean = false;
    private _keys: string[] // Note that this is not initialized

    constructor() {
        this._keys = Object.keys(this);
    }

    toJSON() {
        var obj: any = {};
        this._keys.forEach(key => {
            obj[key] = this[key]
        });
        return obj
    }
}

let car: Car = new Car();
car.model = 'modelA';
car.colour = 'black';
car['active'] = true;

console.log(JSON.stringify({ 'data': car }));
```